# Android FIDO2 conflicts with Zendesk messaging plugin

Tags: android, zendesk, fido-u2f, zendesk-app

I have such a problem, but I can’t figure out how to solve it.

I have in my application `FIDO2` which works with `U2F` keys. After connecting the library there were no problems in debug mode, everything worked as it should, but when I compile the release version, for some reason `FIDO2` it starts to give the wrong `signature`.

Maybe someone can help me understand what the plugin can change during the release of the build, I can’t find it.

I tested a lot, just after connecting `zendesk.messaging:messaging-android` I get this error.